# What's the difference between "people involved" and "involved people"?

Tags: past-participles, participles, participle-clauses, post-modifier, postmodification

I learned at school to put an adjective clause in front of the noun when it consists of only one word and to put it after the noun when it consists of more than one word.

However, I sometimes find a particle after a noun, like "people involved", "the product advertised".

When do you put a particle after a noun?  Is there any difference between "people involved" and "involved people"?  "The product advertised" and "the advertised product"?

Thank you.

Comment: _The people involved_ is short for _The people who are/were involved in [the incident]_. As an adjective, _involved_ usually means _complicated_, so it's not really idiomatic to speak of _involved people_. There is no difference in meaning between _the product advertised_ and _the advertised product_ - it's just a stylistic  choice.

Answer (score 0):

English sentences often leave out (elliptical omission) some "filler" words that don't add direct meaning but might make the grammatical relationships clearer.

In your example, the full phrasing is "the people [who are] involved"

For example:

The complex operation involved a surgical team of three doctors, ten nurses, and two anesthesiologists.

versus

My cousin Lucy is involved with her local Labour party.

or

Thank you for cleaning up the city park, though I know that other people were involved [with this work] behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, [postpositive adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective)

I will take another word as an example because it is more commonly used:  responsible.

If you ask for the "responsible people", you are asking for people who have the attribute "worthy of trust, reliable."

If you ask for the "people responsible," there is an implicit [for this] after the word -- that is, you are asking for the guilty parts.

Wikipedia has more.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is about the effect you are trying to have on the sentence. I would use people involved if I were writing a police statement or something official. Some might use "involved people" when trying to add tone to some sort of literature.

As a literature producer, I try my hardest to not follow the english standard unless it is absolutely necessary so I flow with whatever sounds right. For the correct way of putting together a sentence: I would put a particle with multiple words directly after the word if possible. Like "Product advertised as" or "People unfortunately involved".